# Issue to call message handler (Django Channels)

Tags: python, django, channel

I have this portion of code in my app/views.py (to send signals to the group over the websocket just priori posting a new object in my db):

```
from django.core import serializers
import channels.layers
from .consumers import serialize_games
from asgiref.sync import async_to_sync



def send_game_update(event):
    '''
    Call back function to send message to the browser
    '''
    print('@call_back:into it')
    message = event['message']
    channel_layer = channels.layers.get_channel_layer()
    # Send message to WebSocket
    async_to_sync(channel_layer.send)(text_data=json.dumps(
        message
    ))
    print('@call_back: messages sent to lobby')

def send_update_signal():

    games = serialize_games()
    channel_layer = channels.layers.get_channel_layer()
    # Send new game info to Lobby
    async_to_sync(channel_layer.group_send)( 'Lobby', { 'type': 'send_game_update', 'message': games })
    print('@receiver: just before messages sent to lobby')
```

And django raises:

```
ValueError: No handler for message type send_game_update
Exception inside application: No handler for message type send_game_update
```

Is that a namespace issue?

Comment: I have found the answer: the message handler must be defined in the consumer class definition.